# array count base on how many it appear

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am a newbie in PHP.

I have a mysqli_fetch_array that looks like this inside a while loop"

```
   array(7) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000001"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(5) "admin"
  ["PRODUCT"]=>
  string(32) "Ps4"
}
array(7) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000001"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(5) "mike"
  ["PRODUCT"]=>
  string(32) "Iphone"
}
array(7) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000001"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(5) "mike"
  ["PRODUCT"]=>
  string(32) "Imac"
}
array(7) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000001"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(5) "mike"
  ["PRODUCT"]=>
  string(32) "LCD Monitor"
}
```

I want to count how many times admin and mike appear in the loop: so far I know how to loop:

```
while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
//I don't know what to do next here:
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$admin = 0;$mike = 0;
while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['NAME'] == 'mike') $mike++;
    if($row['NAME'] == 'admin') $admin++;
}
echo $mike; //3
echo $admin; //1
```

Answer (score 2):

**You should ask this information from DATABASE.**

A query like this could do

```
SELECT NAME, count(1) cnt FROM table GROUP BY NAME
```

All other answers here scream for inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $count[$row['NAME']] = isset( $count[$row['NAME']] ) ? $count[$row['NAME']] + 1 : 1;
}
var_dump($count);
```